# Global search in E-Commerce Project: Elastic Nest

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a problem where i am not able to search my search keyword in all documents with each field. I need a functionality where search keyword will search with each field with LIKE functionality. As of now i am using .Match and .Multi_Match for search but it's not full-filling my requirements because if user put multiple words then it's match search key in each field and not found any value. So need support here. In earlier _all function is used in NEST, which was fine but in NEST latest framework there is no _all method. please help us here. if need any information from my side. Please let me know.

I have tried with Match and Multi_Match and MatchAll funcation, but nothing is working to full fill my requirements.

```
enter code here
m => m.MultiMatch(lk =>
                                                                   {
                                                                       var query = new MultiMatchQueryDescriptor<CarSearchRequest>();
                                                                       if (searchAjaxRequest.query != null)
                                                                       {
                                                                           query = lk.Fields(f1 => f1.Fields(f2 => f2.model, f3 => f3.variant, f4 => f4.carType, f5 => f5.fuelType)).Query(searchAjaxRequest.query.ToLower());
                                                                           return query;
                                                                       }
                                                                       return query;
                                                                   }),
```

Answer (score 0):

The `_all` field was [deprecated in Elasticsearch 6.x](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/mapping-all-field.html) and removed in Elasticsearch 7.x. The NEST client reflects this change.

Given the POCO

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
    public bool IsManager { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Hours { get; set; }
}
```

You can create your own `_all`-*like* field using [`copy_to`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.2/copy-to.html) in 7.x

```cs
var client = new ElasticClient();

var createIndexResponse = client.Indices.Create("employees", c => c
    .Map<Employee>(m => m
        .AutoMap()
        .Properties(p => p
            .Text(t => t
                .Name("my_all_field")
                // specify any other settings for my_all_field e.g. analyzer
            )
            // .... etc...
        )
    )   
);
```

You can take advantage of the [visitor pattern for mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/visitor-pattern-mapping.html) here, if for example, you wanted to copy all `string` POCO properties to your `copy_to` field. First create a visitor

```
public class CopyAllStringPropertiesVisitor : NoopPropertyVisitor
{
    public override void Visit(ITextProperty type, PropertyInfo propertyInfo, ElasticsearchPropertyAttributeBase attribute)
    {
        base.Visit(type, propertyInfo, attribute);      
        type.CopyTo = Infer.Fields("my_all_field");
    }
}
```

Then pass it to `AutoMap`

```
var createIndexResponse = client.Indices.Create("employees", c => c
    .Map<Employee>(m => m
        .AutoMap(new CopyAllStringPropertiesVisitor())
        .Properties(p => p
            .Text(t => t
                .Name("my_all_field")
                // specify any other settings for my_all_field e.g. analyzer
            )
        )
    )
);
```

which results in the following mapping

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "firstName": {
        "copy_to": ["my_all_field"],
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        },
        "type": "text"
      },
      "lastName": {
        "copy_to": ["my_all_field"],
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "ignore_above": 256,
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        },
        "type": "text"
      },
      "salary": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "birthday": {
        "type": "date"
      },
      "isManager": {
        "type": "boolean"
      },
      "employees": {
        "properties": {},
        "type": "object"
      },
      "hours": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "my_all_field": {
        "type": "text"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

To use the `copy_to` field at search time

```
var searchResponse = client.Search<Employee>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field("my_all_field")
            .Query("some query input")
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Thanks Russ Cam for replying the perfect solution.

Comment: @sachin if it helps you, consider upvoting and marking as the solution :)